# Value of var is not shown when concatenating $ and var --> $var

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I've got about a day of experience in bash as of now..

```
string () {
    for (( i=0; i<${#1}; i++ ))
    do
        echo "$"${1:$i:1}""
    done
}


string "hello"
```

This script returns "`$h`", "`$e`", "`$l`", "`$l`", "`$o`",
but I actually want it to return the contents of variables `h`, `e`, `l`, `l` and `o`.

**How do I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use indirect parameter expansion:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#1}; i++)); do
    t=${1:i:1}
    echo "${!t}"
done
```

`${!t}` takes the value of `$t`, and treats that as the name of the parameter to expand.

Comment: Note that this only works for bash. zsh equivalent is `${(P)t}`

Comment: The question is only tagged `bash`. We don't need to provide the relevant syntax for every other shell.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it will help someone who is working with zsh and came across this page while googling for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using `eval` to safely write a series of `echo`s to output `bash` *parameter transformation* assignment statements, with *GNU* `grep` divvying up the input string:

```
h=foo o=bar
string() { eval $(printf 'echo ${%s@A};\n' $(grep -o . <<< "$@" )) ; }
string hello
```

Output, (blank lines represent the unset variables `$e` and `$l`):

```
h='foo'



o='bar'
```